# Set cookie, nothing is being shown

Tags: php

This is taken directly from w3's website. I may not be understanding cookies correctly, but why is nothing displaying?

```
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
setcookie("user", "Alex Porter", $expire);
echo $_COOKIE["user"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cookie will only be accessible when you refresh the page or navigate to a new one.

When your script loads, the HTML header fields for that page have already been set. The page will need to be rendered again (another HTTP transaction) before your cookie is available for use. Check [PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed **on the next page load** with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$_COOKIE[]` representates the state at the start of the script. That means that you have to wait on the next page request to see the variable. You could also add your variable manually to the global cookie variable `$_COOKIE['user] = 'Alex Porter';` but the problem is that you are not sure that the browser really accepted the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

check that your browser allows localhost / 127.x.x.x cookies or not ? if it allows then **refresh the page**. If you are using Google Chrome then you can see all browser cookies from here : `chrome://settings/cookies` navigate to localhost / 127.x.x.x to see your code has put cookies or not !